# After deploying new cloud code in Parse, why do some queries use the old code for a short while afterwards?

Tags: parse-platform

I've noticed this several times: I upload new cloud code and run several new test queries from the command line, and I may receive results that appear to have been run (variously) through either the new OR the old code. This might continue for tens of seconds afterwards. Eventually all queries seem to have been run using the new code.

It's mildly annoying as it means my immediate tests aren't to be treated as reliable, but as much as anything I'm interested in what's going on in the back end. Is it that the new code deploys to some back end server nodes faster than others, and random assignment of a new query to the servers may therefore yield inconsistent results for a while?

Comment: I've experienced this on occasion, too.